# Variable not found when using if/else condition but found when using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I have a code below using if/else condition to evaluate what value to assign **addedDocument** based on whether **customId** is not Null.

Why is it that **addedDocument** cannot be found as seen in the picture below?

```
if (customId) {
  const addedDocument = await setDoc(doc(ref), {
    ...documentData,
    createdAt,
  });
} else {
  const addedDocument = await addDoc(ref, { ...documentData, createdAt });
}

dispatchIfNotCancelled({
  type: 'ADDED_DOCUMENT',
  payload: addedDocument,
});
```

[if/else operator causing variable to not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Clo.png)

But can be found when using a ternary operator? As seen in the picture below

```
const addedDocument = customId
  ? await setDoc(doc(ref, customId), { ...documentData, createdAt })
  : await addDoc(ref, { ...documentData, createdAt });

dispatchIfNotCancelled({
  type: 'ADDED_DOCUMENT',
  payload: addedDocument,
});
```

[Ternary operator having no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvqhf.png)

Comment: [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) variables are block-scoped.

Comment: Read the differences about declaring variables with var, let and const keywords. 

var is function scoped, which means it is available only within the function, where you declare it. 

let and const are block scoped, so if you declare them within scope {} , they are available only there.

Comment: Thanks. I always thought the scope only means function { }. Didn't knew that if/else { } was also consider a scope.